# How to do left join twice in one query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to do left join twice or other way to get data in result list like below in one query ?

I want `media_information` under `media`

```
{ 
  id: 9,
  gallery_id: 25,
  media_id: 9,
  media: { 
    id: 9,
    media_information: {
      id: 9,
      media_id: 9,
    }
  },
}
```

query I tried

```
var dbQuery = `SELECT
  gm.*,
  row_to_json(m.*) as media,
  row_to_json(mi.*) as media_information
  FROM "gallery_media" gm 
  LEFT JOIN media m ON gm.media_id = m.id
  LEFT JOIN media_information mi ON gm.media_id = mi.media_id
  WHERE "gallery_id" = $1 
  ORDER BY gm.create_date DESC OFFSET $2 LIMIT $3`;
```

result

```
{ 
  id: 9,
  gallery_id: 25,
  media_id: 9,
  media: { 
    id: 9,
  },
  media_information: {
    id: 9,
    media_id: 9,
  }
}
```

UPDATE

I also tried change `ON m.id = mi.media_id` but result nothing change

```
var dbQuery = `SELECT
  gm.*,
  row_to_json(m.*) as media,
  row_to_json(mi.*) as media_information
  FROM "gallery_media" gm 
  LEFT JOIN media m ON gm.media_id = m.id
  LEFT JOIN media_information mi ON m.id = mi.media_id
  WHERE "gallery_id" = $1 
  ORDER BY gm.create_date DESC OFFSET $2 LIMIT $3`;
```

table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "gallery_media"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "gallery_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "media_id" integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
  );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "media"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "media_information"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "media_id" integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")  );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ff805

Comment: I want to know how to do in one query? now I separate query left join `media` to `gallery_media` then select` media_information` user `media_id`

Comment: You just need to change your query so that the second `left join` joins to the table in the first `left join`.

Comment: @dan1111 how? I can't get it.. can you show me example

Comment: `WHERE "gallery_id" = $1` which table does gallery_id come from ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
var dbQuery = `SELECT                                    
  gm.*,                                                  
  row_to_json(m.*) as media,                             
  row_to_json(mi.*) as media_information                 
  FROM "gallery_media" gm                                
  LEFT JOIN media m ON gm.media_id = m.id                
  LEFT JOIN media_information mi ON m.id = mi.media_id   
  WHERE "gallery_id" = $1                                
  ORDER BY gm.create_date DESC OFFSET $2 LIMIT $3`;
```

ie: doing your second `LEFT JOIN` on `media` instead of `gallery_media`

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried this before but get same result, nothing change

Comment: @user1575921 Then I'd suggest to post a SQL Fiddle of your struct and data so we can play around it.